# PDF reader for Mac: stripping white background

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, ebook

I'm in search of a PDF reader capable of stripping the white background of a pdf page and applying a theme in place of it.

For example, I use Ibouquiniste on my iOS devices: it has the capability of putting a very paperlike theme in place of the eye-annoying white background.

Is there anything similar for Mac?

Comment: modifying existing or creating new document.

Comment: You might looking at adding a watermark giving that kind of texture. (but then, why??)

Comment: I'd prefer not to modify or editing files. I want an app capable of adding textured background on the fly. Many apps for ios and android do that, I cannot understand why one cannot have it on a desktop machine..

Comment: Probably a question of history. PDFs were developed out of the postscript language (for printing).  Desktop computers still treat PDFs like a pre-print document hence historically they were not looking to add features that make the documents look different from the printed page.  Conversely printing is not well-supported on mobile devices so adding backgrounds is not contrary to intent of the technology.